# Setting variable limits for cytoscape.js mapData

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Quick question. I am trying to use cytoscape's.js mapData linear mapper to set the colour of edges in a small plot.
There is, however, a small problem. The following example works without a hitch.

```
.selector('edge')
    .css({
       'line-color': 'mapData(similarity,1.8,3.78, blue, red)'
       'width': 2,
       'opacity': 0.8
  })
```

However, as soon as a I replace the fixed boundaries, I am in a bit of a pickle.

```
.selector('edge')
    .css({
        'line-color': 'mapData(similarity,min, max, blue, red)',
        'width': 2,
        'opacity': 0.8
 })
```

the coloured edges disappear, and all turn grey. The min and max variables are set prior, and I can verify this because they are being used to calculate other stuff before the graph is created. I have looked through the documentation but cannot find anything regarding this issue.

As @dandavis suggested, It might be a plugin thing. So I tried adding the to add the max and min to each edge json definition. This was done thinking that maybe the mapData function assumes that whenever a "variable" is used, they are stored in the definition of the appropriate selector.

```
id: "133700_307800"
max_sim: 3.57829530512
min_sim: 1.9655114484
similarity: 3.57829530512
source: "133700"
target: "307800"
```

Any ideas?

thanks a lot!

Comment: since it's not normal css, a plugin probably translates it, and that plugin probably wants hard-coded data, not variable references it might not be able to see if it's Function()-based.

Comment: Thanks!  have edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect variables to be evaluated in strings in JS (except with the upcoming ES6 feature, if used explicitly).  So,

`.selector('edge')
    .css({
       'line-color': 'mapData(similarity,min, max, blue, red)'
       'width': 2,
       'opacity': 0.8
  })`

becomes

`.selector('edge')
    .css({
       'line-color': 'mapData(similarity,' + min + ', ' + max + ', blue, red)'
       'width': 2,
       'opacity': 0.8
  })`

and so on.

Comment: Cheers @maxkfranz. Just a follow up, what is the difference between similarity (which is a value in the json) and min and max? I have tried storing the min and max in the json as well, but that approach did not pan out.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to set variable boundaries for the mapData function to no avail. What I ended up doing was scale the values between 0 and 1, and and fix the lower and upper boundaries in the javascript. Thank you!